Pytest monkeypatch a multiprocess function for testing
Pytest monkeypatching a function that uses multiprocess (via concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) does not work as expected. If the same function is written with a single process or multithread (via concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor), monkeypatch works as expected.
Why does multiprocess monkeypatch fail and how does one correctly monkeypatch a multiprocess function for testing?
Simplest code example to illustrate my question is below. In actual usage, I would try to monkeypatch a function imported from another module.
# file_a.py

import concurrent.futures as ccf

MY_CONSTANT = "hello"

def my_function():
    return MY_CONSTANT


def singleprocess_f():
    result = []
    for _ in range(3):
        result.append(my_function())
    return result


def multithread_f():
    result = []
    with ccf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for _ in range(3):
            future = executor.submit(my_function)
            futures.append(future)
        for future in ccf.as_completed(futures):
            result.append(future.result())
    return result


def multiprocess_f():
    result = []
    with ccf.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for _ in range(3):
            future = executor.submit(my_function)
            futures.append(future)
        for future in ccf.as_completed(futures):
            result.append(future.result())
    return result


I expected all tests to pass (pip install -U pytest, run tests with pytest test_file_a.py):
# test_file_a.py

from file_a import multiprocess_f, multithread_f, singleprocess_f

# PASSES:
def test_singleprocess_f(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("file_a.MY_CONSTANT", "world")
    result = singleprocess_f()
    assert result == ["world"] * 3

# PASSES:
def test_multithread_f(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("file_a.MY_CONSTANT", "world")
    result = multithread_f()
    assert result == ["world"] * 3

# FAILS:
def test_multiprocess_f(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("file_a.MY_CONSTANT", "world")
    result = multiprocess_f()
    assert result == ["world"] * 3


What is monkeypatch? See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. And what platform are you running on? One that uses spawn?

@Booboo Clarified that monkeypatch is a pytest fixture, thanks for catching that. Running on macOS, but would be ideal if tests were os agnostic.

Good to know. I have updated my answer with the approach I would take.

My guess is that you are running on some platform that uses by default the spawn method for creating new processes (e.g. Windows). If that is the case, it does not matter what value you assign to MY_CONSTANT in the main process, using monkeypatch or otherwise, because when the child pool processes are created they will initialize its memory by re-executing the statement MY_CONSTANT = "hello". That is, child processes created with spawn do not inherit any values from the parent process but instead initialize memory by executing all statements at global scope (e.g. import statement, function and variable declarations, etc.).
If this is the case, then you must therefore provide a pool initializer function using the initializer argument when creating your ProcessPoolExecutor instance. Function multiprocessing_f needs to participate in its testing by accepting an optional executor argument (a multiprocessing pool) to be used for testing:
File file_a.py
import concurrent.futures as ccf


MY_CONSTANT = "hello"


def my_function():
    return MY_CONSTANT


def singleprocess_f():
    result = []
    for _ in range(3):
        result.append(my_function())
    return result


def multithread_f():
    result = []
    with ccf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for _ in range(3):
            future = executor.submit(my_function)
            futures.append(future)
        for future in ccf.as_completed(futures):
            result.append(future.result())
    return result


def multiprocess_f(executor=None):
    """To allow unit testing, we may be passed an executor
    to use."""

    if executor is None:
        executor = ccf.ProcessPoolExecutor()

    result = []
    with executor:
        futures = []
        for _ in range(3):
            future = executor.submit(my_function)
            futures.append(future)
        for future in ccf.as_completed(futures):
            result.append(future.result())
    return result

File test_file_a.py
import concurrent.futures as ccf

import file_a

def init_pool_processes():
    file_a.MY_CONSTANT = "world"


# PASSES:
def test_singleprocess_f(monkeypatch):
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        monkeypatch.setattr(file_a, "MY_CONSTANT", "world")
        result = file_a.singleprocess_f()
        assert result == ["world"] * 3

# PASSES:
def test_multithread_f(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(file_a, "MY_CONSTANT", "world")
    result = file_a.multithread_f()
    assert result == ["world"] * 3

# PASSES:
def test_multiprocess_f():
    # Special executor for testing:
    executor = ccf.ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=init_pool_processes)
    result = file_a.multiprocess_f(executor)
    assert result == ["world"] * 3

